# Wait until two observables emit true

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a container `Fragment` that holds two `Fragments` on a `ViewPager`. I want to wait until these two `Fragments` are ready to fetch some data. I have created a `ViewPagerFragment` class that holds this BehaviorSubject:

```
val viewReady : BehaviorSubject<Boolean> = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(false)

 @CallSuper
override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewReady.onNext(true)
}
```

**I subscribe to this from my Container `Fragment`:**

```
var tab1ready = tab1fragment.viewReady()
var tab2ready = tab2fragment.viewReady()
```

I want to combine these two in the following manner:

"When the two of them have emitted true, then call method `fetchData()`"

I am struggling on finding the proper way to do this that does not revolve in keeping a boolean for each and checking on each emision if both booleans are true.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are looking for the `zip()` operator.

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html

`merge()` might work for you too though.
`join()` is a time sensitive alternative.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Combining-Observables

Answer (score 0):

Solution #1: *.filter()* each observable on 'true', *.zip()* both, *.take(1)*.

Solution #2: *Observable.combineLatest()*, *.filter()* on both being 'true', *.take(1)*.

Comment: will this ensure i get a true on both?

Comment: yes, if you use .filter() which checks whether value is true